# Using order by DESC or ASC in mysql queries with UNION keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

In my page I used the following query for displaying choices starts from current time to old time of choices. But it selects the row starts from old time choices to current time choices.

I want to display the choices starts from current time to old one

```
$result=mysql_query("(SELECT choice_id,poll_id,choicecreationtime from je_addchoice ORDER BY choicecreationtime DESC)
    UNION
    (SELECT choice_id,poll_id,datetime_voted from je_user_vote ORDER BY datetime_voted DESC)");
```

I dont know why this problem occurs. If I don't use the UNION means it works fine. For example. The below query shows the order of current time to old

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM je_addchoice, je_addpoll where je_addpoll.privacy='0' AND je_addpoll.start_date <= '$check_date' AND je_addpoll.end_date >='$check_date'  AND je_addpoll.poll_id=je_addchoice.poll_id order by je_addchoice.choicecreationtime desc");
```

Anybody can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [`UNION` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html):

> To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html), place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html):
>
> ```sql
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```
>
> However, use of `ORDER BY` for individual [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of `ORDER BY` in this context is typically in conjunction with `LIMIT`, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html), even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) result. If `ORDER BY` appears without `LIMIT` in a [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html), it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.
>
> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) result, parenthesize the individual [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:
>
> ```sql
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
> ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as just shown.

Answer (score 4):

wrap the `union`ed queries by subquery and order them on the outer query

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT choice_id, poll_id, choicecreationtime AS TIME
        FROM je_addchoice
        UNION
        SELECT choice_id, poll_id, datetime_voted AS TIME
        FROM je_user_vote
    ) s
ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT choice_id, poll_id, choicecreationtime AS TIME
FROM je_addchoice
UNION
SELECT choice_id, poll_id, datetime_voted AS TIME
FROM je_user_vote
ORDER BY Time DESC
```

Comment: The outermost `SELECT` is unnecessary.

Comment: @eggyal is there any difference?

Comment: Semantically, no.  But I don't know whether the optimiser treats the two differently...

Comment: SO. no need for the outermost SELECT? Then how can sort the order

Comment: The "SELECT a UNION b" construct allows only one ORDER BY, which applies to the union as a whole. BTW: the inner (a,b) queries will need *some kind* of sorting, because the duplicates have to be removed (unless UNION ALL is used)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT choice_id, poll_id, dt
FROM (SELECT choice_id, poll_id, choicecreationtime dt FROM je_addchoice 
      UNION 
      SELECT choice_id, poll_id, datetime_voted dt FROM je_user_vote ) AS A
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Comment: The outermost `SELECT` is unnecessary.